# Python - count and group items in list stored in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, collections, grouping

I have seen examples on how to count items in dictionary or list. My dictionary stored multiple lists.  Each list stores multiple items.

```
d = dict{}
d  = {'text1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F'], 
      'text2': ['A'], 
      'text3': ['C', 'D'], 
      'text4': ['A', 'B'], 
      'text5': ['A']}
```

**1.** I want to count frequency of each alphabet, i.e. the results should be

```
A - 4  
B - 1  
C - 2  
D - 1  
E - 1  
F - 1
```

**2.** I want to have group by each alphabet, i.e. the results should be

```
A - text1, text2, text4, text5  
B - text4  
C - text1, text3  
D - text3  
E - text1  
F - text1
```

How can I achieve both by using some Python existing libraries without using many for loops?

Comment: Will the lists ever have duplicates?

Comment: So where did you fail? Please post your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: I do not have other codes yet.  I can write loops to find the answers but I bet there must be some library (collections?) to do it.

Comment: The list does not have duplicates

Comment: What do you consider 'many' for loops? They exist for a reason, and this use case is a good one for them. Do you have a reaosn for wanting to avoid them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get to (2), you would have to first invert the keys and values of a dictionary, and store them in a list. Once you are there, use `groupby` with a key to get to the structure of (2).

```
from itertools import groupby

arr = [(x,t) for t, a in d.items() for x in a]
# [('A', 'text2'), ('C', 'text3'), ('D', 'text3'), ('A', 'text1'), ('C', 'text1'), ('E', 'text1'), ('F', 'text1'), ('A', 'text4'), ('B', 'text4'), ('A', 'text5')]

res = {g: [x[1] for x in items] for g, items in groupby(sorted(arr), key=lambda x: x[0])}
#{'A': ['text1', 'text2', 'text4', 'text5'], 'C': ['text1', 'text3'], 'B': ['text4'], 'E': ['text1'], 'D': ['text3'], 'F': ['text1']}

res2 = {x: len(y) for x, y in res.items()}
#{'A': 4, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'E': 1, 'D': 1, 'F': 1}
```

PS: I am hoping you'd meaningful variable names in your real code.

Comment: Can you explain the res line? How groupby and lambda are used together?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, but if you'd like to handle things without worrying about `import` ing additional modules or installing and importing external modules, this method will work cleanly 'out of the box.'

With `d` as your starting dictionary:

```
d  = {'text1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F'], 
      'text2': ['A'], 
      'text3': ['C', 'D'], 
      'text4': ['A', 'B'], 
      'text5': ['A']}
```

create a new `dict`, called `letters`, for your results to live in, and populate it with your letters, taken from `d.keys()`, by creating the letter key if it isn't present, and creating a list with the count and the key from `d`as it's value. If it's already there, increment the count, and append the current key from `d` to it's `d` key list in the value.

```
letters = {}
for item in d.keys():
    for letter in d[item]:
        if letter not in letters.keys():
            letters[letter] = [1,[item]]            
        else:
            letters[letter][0] += 1
            letters[letter][1] += [item]
```

This leaves you with a `dict` called `letters` containing values of the counts and the keys from `d` that contain the letter, like this:

```
{'E': [1, ['text1']], 'C': [2, ['text3', 'text1']], 'F': [1, ['text1']], 'A': [4, ['text2', 'text4', 'text1', 'text5']], 'B': [1, ['text4']], 'D': [1, ['text3']]}`
```

Now, to print your first list, do:

```
for letter in sorted(letters):
    print(letter, letters[letter][0])
```

printing each letter and the contents of the first, or 'count' index of the list as its value, and using the built-in `sorted()` function to put things in order.

To print the second, likewise `sorted()`, do the same, but with the second, or 'key', index of the list in its value, `.joined` using a `,` into a string:

```
for letter in sorted(letters):
    print(letter, ', '.join(letters[letter][1]))
```

To ease Copy/Paste, here's the code unbroken by my ramblings:

```
d  = {'text1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F'], 
      'text2': ['A'], 
      'text3': ['C', 'D'], 
      'text4': ['A', 'B'], 
      'text5': ['A']}

letters = {}
for item in d.keys():
    for letter in d[item]:
        if letter not in letters.keys():
            letters[letter] = [1,[item]]            
        else:
            letters[letter][0] += 1
            letters[letter][1] += [item]

print(letters)

for letter in letters:
    print(letter, letters[letter][0])
print()
for letter in letters:
    print(letter, ', '.join(letters[letter][1]))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import chain
d  = {'text1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F'], 
      'text2': ['A'], 
      'text3': ['C', 'D'], 
      'text4': ['A', 'B'], 
      'text5': ['A']}
counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
group = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        group[i].append(k)
```

out:

```
Counter({'A': 4, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'E': 1, 'F': 1})
defaultdict(list,
            {'A': ['text2', 'text4', 'text1', 'text5'],
             'B': ['text4'],
             'C': ['text1', 'text3'],
             'D': ['text3'],
             'E': ['text1'],
             'F': ['text1']})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

alphabets = defaultdict(list)
his is a way to acheive this:

    for text, letters in d.items():
        for letter in letters:
            alphabets[letter].append(text)

    for letter, texts in sorted(alphabets.items()):
        print(letter, texts)

    for letter, texts in sorted(alphabets.items()):
        print(letter, len(texts))
```

note that if you have `A - text1, text2, text4, text5` to get to `A - 4` is just a matter of counting the texts.

Answer (score 0):

For your first task:

```
from collections import Counter


d = {
  'text1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F'],
  'text2': ['A'],
  'text3': ['C', 'D'],
  'text4': ['A', 'B'],
  'text5': ['A']
}

occurrences = Counter(''.join(''.join(values) for values in d.values()))
print(sorted(occurrences.items(), key=lambda l: l[0]))
```

Now let me explain it:

- **''.join(values)** turns the list (e.g. **['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']** into **'ABCD'**)
- Then you **join** each list from the dictionary into one string (the outer **''.join()**)
- **Counter** is a class from the builtin package **collections**, which simply counts the elements in the iterable (**string** in this case) and reproduces them as tuples of **(key, value)** pairs (e.g. **('A', 4)**)
- Finally, I sort the **Counter** items (it's just like a dictionary) alphabetically (**key=lambda l: l[0]** where **l[0]** is the letter from the **(key, value)** pair.

As I saw, you already have the solution for your second problem.